# google crawl ajax

Tags: ajax, web-crawler

I have result page where result is loading with ajax which mean that pagination buttons are calling JS. The link to result page is beautiful '/result/sell/06589' and I will guide google to this page but is there way to make crawl bot to click on pagination buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make them not buttons but links which are styled as buttons.

Also, you need to make sure that that they works without Javascript too! Crawlers generally don't have Javascript.